# What is wrong with this SQL command?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connector

**Solution:** I noticed the length of my passed variable, Username, was over 65k. This led me to see I set ReceiveBufferSize wrong. This would only become apparent if I needed to check a unique value, and that value was the last value in the stream. In my "working" command, Username was the second command. If you're in a similar situation, use QuickWatch and pay very close attention. It may be whitespace causing those values to not match.

```
Public Function Before_Logon(ByVal Username As String) As String
            Try
                mySqlCon.Open()
                Dim sqlCommandPreLogon As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username=@username", mySqlCon)
                sqlCommandPreLogon.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username)
                Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = sqlCommandPreLogon.ExecuteReader()
                While dr.Read
                    Return dr.Item(0).ToString
                End While
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            Return 6
        End Function
```

I have a command just like this in another function, and it works fine. This one doesn't find anything. Removing Try/Catch shows no errors.

This does't work either.

```
 Dim sqlCommandPreLogon As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username='" & Username & "'", mySqlCon)
```

This does work, oddly enough.

```
 Dim sqlCommandPreLogon As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username='user'", mySqlCon)
```

Why exactly do variables/sql parameter values not work, but this does?

Update: Nothing seems wrong when I look at the parameter through QuickWatch. First is the working command, second is the one that's not.

```
test    {@uname}    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter
BaseName    uname   String
Collection  {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection}   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection
DbType  String {16} System.Data.DbType
Direction   Input {1}   System.Data.ParameterDirection
Encoding    Nothing System.Text.Encoding
IsNullable  FALSE   Boolean
MySqlDbType VarChar {253}   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType
ParameterName   @uname  String
PossibleValues  Nothing System.Collections.IList
Precision   0   Byte
Precision (DbParameter) 0   Byte
Scale   0   Byte
Scale (DbParameter) 0   Byte
Size    65533   Integer
SourceColumn    Nothing String
SourceColumnNullMapping FALSE   Boolean
SourceVersion   Current {512}   System.Data.DataRowVersion
TypeHasBeenSet  TRUE    Boolean
Value   new {String}    Object
String  new String
ValueObject {MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString}  MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue
MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString    {MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString}  MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString
IsNull  TRUE    Boolean
Value       String

test    {@uname}    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter
BaseName    uname   String
Collection  {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection}   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection
DbType  String {16} System.Data.DbType
Direction   Input {1}   System.Data.ParameterDirection
Encoding    Nothing System.Text.Encoding
IsNullable  FALSE   Boolean
MySqlDbType VarChar {253}   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType
ParameterName   @uname  String
PossibleValues  Nothing System.Collections.IList
Precision   0   Byte
Precision (DbParameter) 0   Byte
Scale   0   Byte
Scale (DbParameter) 0   Byte
Size    3   Integer
SourceColumn    Nothing String
SourceColumnNullMapping FALSE   Boolean
SourceVersion   Current {512}   System.Data.DataRowVersion
TypeHasBeenSet  TRUE    Boolean
Value   new {String}    Object
String  new String
ValueObject {MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString}  MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue
MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString    {MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString}  MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString
IsNull  TRUE    Boolean
Value       String
```

Here's the difference between `'user'` and `' & Username & '` in order.

```
test    {@uname}    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter
BaseName    uname   String
Collection  {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection}   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection
DbType  String {16} System.Data.DbType
Direction   Input {1}   System.Data.ParameterDirection
Encoding    Nothing System.Text.Encoding
IsNullable  FALSE   Boolean
MySqlDbType VarChar {253}   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType
ParameterName   @uname  String
PossibleValues  Nothing System.Collections.IList
Precision   0   Byte
Precision (DbParameter) 0   Byte
Scale   0   Byte
Scale (DbParameter) 0   Byte
Size    65533   Integer
SourceColumn    Nothing String
SourceColumnNullMapping FALSE   Boolean
SourceVersion   Current {512}   System.Data.DataRowVersion
TypeHasBeenSet  TRUE    Boolean
Value   user {String}   Object
String  user    String
ValueObject {MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString}  MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue
MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString    {MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString}  MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString
IsNull  TRUE    Boolean
Value       String

test    {@uname}    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter
BaseName    uname   String
Collection  {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection}   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection
DbType  String {16} System.Data.DbType
Direction   Input {1}   System.Data.ParameterDirection
Encoding    Nothing System.Text.Encoding
IsNullable  FALSE   Boolean
MySqlDbType VarChar {253}   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType
ParameterName   @uname  String
PossibleValues  Nothing System.Collections.IList
Precision   0   Byte
Precision (DbParameter) 0   Byte
Scale   0   Byte
Scale (DbParameter) 0   Byte
Size    65533   Integer
SourceColumn    Nothing String
SourceColumnNullMapping FALSE   Boolean
SourceVersion   Current {512}   System.Data.DataRowVersion
TypeHasBeenSet  TRUE    Boolean
Value   user {String}   Object
String  user    String
ValueObject {MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString}  MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue
MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString    {MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString}  MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString
IsNull  TRUE    Boolean
Value       String
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  Your first example is an entirely pointless query because you're fetching a value that you *already have*.  Your second example is a glaring SQL injection vulnerability and should never be used.  Your third example doesn't use the input value at all and just uses a hard-coded value.  What are you trying to do and in what way is it failing?

Comment: it is not working because the ultimate string to execute is different or goofed up, which is easily seen if you save it to a string and examine it through debugging

Comment: First example could be used to verify a name exists. However, I am really pulling another column. When that wouldn't work, I defaulted to something I knew worked. When that worked, I became very frustrated. Obviously the second example is open for SQL injection. Examples two and three are tests. I started off using parameters because that's the only way you should write it.

Comment: @Drew Updated OP with QuickWatch result. Nothing seems out of place.

Comment: run mysqlcommand with a variable as parameter 1. Compare the version that works versus the one that doesn't.

Comment: It's also worth noting that your code is *completely ignoring all exceptions*.  If code isn't working the way you expect, *ignoring errors* isn't a very effective way to diagnose the problem.  As it stands now, there isn't really anything we can do.  If you're successfully running a `SELECT` command and getting unexpected results, then either you're not running the command you think you are or you don't have the data you think you have.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not entirely concerned about error handling at this point. At some point, yet it will have plenty. But I'd much rather focus on getting it working. I've removed Try/Catch from the block, but saw no errors. I'm debugging this by Stepping Into each line. I'm not seeing any errors. I can't imagine there being any since this is literally the same code. Even when I copy and pasted it, it wouldn't work.

Comment: I am noticing `Size    65533   Integer` despite the length only being 4. The working statement correctly reports size as 3.

Comment: well I think it is a good question. You show research effort, and support your question with very timely response. Good luck!

Comment: And you stayed persistent. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome. It is usually a fault of mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said

This does't work either.

```
 Dim sqlCommandPreLogon As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username='" & Username & "'", mySqlCon)
```

This does work, oddly enough.

```
 Dim sqlCommandPreLogon As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username='user'", mySqlCon)
```

---

so how about this

```
Dim sSql1 As String
Dim sSql2 As String

sSql1 = "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username='" & Username & "'"
sSql2 = "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username='user'"
```

And do QuickWatch on sSql1 and sSql2 and compare them

Comment: Updated as requested.

Comment: The first set, the only different was size. In this set, all values are identical. At least, according to Excel (applying a fill if values are duplicates).

Comment: where is the quickwatch on sSql1 and sSql2. I don't see it, and am off on another question

Comment: sSql1: `sSql1 SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username'user String`
sSql2:   `sSql2 "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username='user'" String`

Comment: Now, you may have wondered where's the other '. It took me longer than expected because I tried copying sSql1, and it told me I was at 65k characters. Then I realized, there are legitimately ~65k whitespace characters. It makes sense why the length is 65k. I'm trying to figure out why my variable is doing this. Something I easily missed in QuickWatch the first time...

Comment: there ya go. Jam it into a variable and the truth shall set you free !

Comment: Eh, not so fast! QuickWatching the passed variable shows no whitespaces. It looks fine. It's the combining which gets screwy...

Comment: what matters is what you are executing. And you now see it.

Comment: It looks like when the variable is concatenated, then I see the whitespaces. Username.Length shows 65k length. So clearly something is wrong with it.

Comment: then you need a trim or the like, or you are working against a fixed space datatype

Comment: That's because the BUFFER SIZE is too big. These statements are being sent from a client (TCPClient/TCPListener). I'm still learning, but the buffer size is at a 65k max. I didn't immediately see it because I never checked those values. However, I did remember seeing my final value is the array have a ton of odd symbols. It makes sense now that those characters were the whitespace. In this function, my ending value is Username which would become apparent now.